# How to open local files from google docs

Tags: android

How to open local files which are stored in my android device local storage  using google docs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Google Documents API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#UploadingDocs) to upload them, and then to open them.